# Trying a version of takeWhile on trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

Given a tree that looks like this:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

And a fold function that looks like this:

```
foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree _ b Leaf         = b
foldTree fn b (Node lt x rt) = f (foldTree fn b lt) x (foldTree fn b rt)
```

I want to be able to write a takeWhileTree function that looks like this:

```
treeTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

I want it to mimic the 'normal' list takeWhile function so that it returns the largest possible tree whose elements satisfy the given condition.

So, if a tree `t = Node (Node Leaf 10 Leaf) 4 (Node Leaf 5 Leaf)`, then:

```
treeTakeWhile (> 5) T = Leaf
treeTakeWhile (>= 4) T = T
treeTakeWhile (< 5) T = Node Leaf 4 Leaf
treeTakeWHile (< 8) T = Node Leaf 4 (Node Leaf 5 Leaf)
```

So far I seem to not be able to formulate what to pass into foldTree. 
In the definition of foldtree, the function can be broken down as: b probably being the left subtree, a probably being the value in the current node and b probably being the right subtree.

Therefore, the function passed to treeTakeWhile has to be applied to all these parts of the node in some manner while being able to stop when the operation no longer applies.

```
treeTakeWhile fn = foldTree (\xs x ys -> if y then g else Leaf) Node()
              where g = (lt, x, rt)
                    y = fn (Node lt x rt)
```

The above is clearly wrong but I am not sure how to express the act of applying the function to the current node's value followed by the left tree and the right tree here. Could somebody point me in the right direction? And how will the fold be able to produce the required tree?

Edit 1:

Okay, based on your feedback, I have gotten to a place where I think I am pretty close to the answer but cannot figure out why the compiler still complains:

```
treeTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeTakeWhile c = foldTree f acc
        where acc = Leaf
              f l x r = if c x then Node (f lt) x (f rt) else Leaf
```

As far as I can tell, foldTree is being passed the right arguments now. And the predicate is also being evaluated as required at each level of the tree. The return value is always of type Tree as well.

Comment: Perhaps you better first aim to define it *without* the `foldTree`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `foldTree` immediately, let's first aim to define the function itself.

Basically there are three options here:

1. the tree is a `Leaf`, regardless what the condition is, the result is a `Leaf` as well;
2. the tree is a `Node` and the condition is satsified, then we yield the element, and recurse on the subtrees;
3. the tree is a `Node` and the condition is *not* satisfied, then the result is a `Leaf`.

We can encode these rules as:

```
treeTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeTakeWhile c = go
    where go Leaf = Leaf                                -- (1)
          go (Node l x r) | c x = Node (go l) x (go r)  -- (2)
                          | otherwise = Leaf            -- (3)
```

this then yields the expected results:

```
Prelude> treeTakeWhile (>5) t
Leaf
Prelude> treeTakeWhile (>=4) t
Node (Node Leaf 10 Leaf) 4 (Node Leaf 5 Leaf)
Prelude> treeTakeWhile (<5) t
Node Leaf 4 Leaf
Prelude> treeTakeWhile (<8) t
Node Leaf 4 (Node Leaf 5 Leaf)
```

## Moving this to a `foldTree`

Now we aim to move the logic to a `foldTree`, we can thus write the function as:

```
treeTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeTakeWhile c = foldTree f x0
    where f tl x tr = -- ...
          x0 = -- ...
```

The `x0` is the value we should fill in for `Leaf`s, but we already know what that is: it is the first rule (1) and we should thus return a `Leaf` as well.

For `f` we need a function `Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a`. The first operand `tl` is the `treeTakeWhile` of the left subtree (this would be equivalent to `go l` in the original function implementation), the second parameter `x` is the value encoded in the `Node`, and the last parameter `tr` is the result of `treeTakeWhile` on the second subtree (so equivalent to `go r`), so:

```
treeTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeTakeWhile c = foldTree f x0
    where f tl x tr = -- ...
          x0 = -- ...
```

(leave this as an exercise).

Comment: Well llike specified before, on `lt` and `rt`, the `treeTakeWhile` has already been applied: these are *not* trees, but already "folded" elements.

Comment: I moved my comment into the original post to preserve formatting

Comment: @azureus: yes, but it was clear, the point is that in case of a "fold", the fold is already applied (well lazily) done to the *parameters* `l` and `r`, so `f l`, etc. makes no sense.

Comment: Oh! I see. Wow, these folds really did a number on me. Thank you so much. I am still getting used to reasoning this way. Could you point me to places where I can improve my skills especially when it comes to working with these fairly 'primitive' abstractions in the language?

Comment: The LYAH book can be a good start I think http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds

Comment: I have been using LYAH fairly actively and I feel like I have a decent handle on list folds but I guess I haven't got used to the lazy aspect of it and was not able to extend it effectively when reasoning with trees

Comment: @azureus: well essentially most "folds" are *catamorphisms* (a concept from *category* theory) so perhaps the wiki page can provide some insights https://wiki.haskell.org/Catamorphisms although category theory is rather "abstract" (well it takes some "chewing" before you start appreciating it :)

Comment: Not to give away the ans but make sure you do not wrap your node construction params in parenthesis. I just spent a good hour wondering why my code looked perfectly logical but wouldn't compile due to type errors. Oh the joys of switching from modern languages to haskell haha.